# Why does passing a prop infinite loop crash my app and doesn't even update the prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am just trying to get one variable from one component to another. Its not suppose to be hard but it is what it is. I have a Search bar, and I want whatever it has to display in another component.

```
class SearchButton extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: "",
        }
    }
updateSearch(event){
        this.setState({
            search: event.target.value
        })
     
    }
  componentDidUpdate(){
        this.setState((props) => ({ search: this.state.search}));
        console.log(this.state.search)
    }
render() { 
        
        return(
            <div>
                 <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Control 
                                type="text" 
                                placeholder="search" 
                                value = {this.state.search} 
                                onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
                            
                            />
                 </Form.Group>
                 <Displayer
                    search={this.state.search}
                 />
            </div>
    }
```

```
class Displayer extends Component {
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        search:""
        }

 render() { 
        return (
        {this.state.search}
        )
    }
}
```

Problem is that this neither updates the prop nor works because if I change the stuff in the search bar SOMETHING updates infinitely and crashes my app but it isn't the Displayer.

Comment: `Displayer` is using `search` from state, not props. As-is it will never update. You probably do not need the state in that component at all.

Comment: Alright I changed it to JSON.stringify(this.props.search) but it still doesn't update and still goes in to an infinite loop then crashes @BrianThompson

Comment: Why would you need `JSON.stringify`? The prop is not an object. There is already an answer pointing it out as the problem, but what are you expecting the `componentDidUpdate` to do? Even if it didn't cause and infinite loop, what logic is it supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs on infinite loop because you are using `componentDidUpdate` in the search bar and that is setting the `state` again, which causes a component update, which updates state, and again and again.

Also you are not using the `search` prop in `Displayer` component correctly.

After setting the `state` you should not set the same `state` again in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

Here is the correct way to do it.

```js
class SearchButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
    }
  }

  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Displayer
          search={this.state.search}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
class Displayer extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.search
  }
}
```

You need to learn what each `react` class component lifecycle is used for.

Here is link to docs [React Component State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: This was amazing. Thank you this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Displayer extends Component {
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

 render() { 
        return (
        <pre>{ props.search }</pre>
        )
    }
}
```

instead of this.state.search, you should use props.search instead as you were passing the props from your parent component.

Comment: I did that but it still goes into an infinite loop and doesn't update